# list 7 instead of 8 in the process of changing number to binary

Tags: python, binary

```
def number_to_byte(number):
       if type(number) != int:
        raise TypeError
    if  number not in range(0,255):
        raise ValueError
    if (number==0):
        return [0]
    else:
        new_bin =[]
        while (number):
            number=number//2
            new_bin.append(number%2)
        new_bin.reverse()
        return new_bin
```

This returned [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1] instead of [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1] (which has 8 booleans). I am trying to write this as a code without bin() and have exactly 8 booleans. Any wisdom?..

I will edit if needed.

Comment: You're shifting it before you do your saving. Put the `//=` at the end of your iteration. If you have just 4 bits in your number (like 15) it probably won't put all the bits.

Comment: May I ask where is the iteration? Sorry, I am just new to learning python languages. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your `while()` loop starts with the number you chose. The first thing you do is shift it right by 1 bit, meaning you lose the least-significant bit. Then you save the least significant bit at the time, and you continue on to with your loop. The loop exits the moment `number` becomes zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use bit-wise operators if you're working with bits.

```py
def number_to_byte(number):
    if not isinstance(number, int):
        raise TypeError
    if number not in range(0,255):
        raise ValueError
    if (number == 0):
        return [0]
    else:
        return [1 if number & (1 << (7 - bit)) else 0 for bit in range(8)]
```